# Is it a good idea to make your jpa entities as spring component

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I came across this question whether one should create the jpa entities using new keyword or
Make your entities as spring component with prototype scope and get the bean from Application Context.

I personally feel we shouldn't make your entities as spring components and create them ourselves rather than asking it from Spring.

Comment: No, they should definitely not be Spring components. Spring doesn't create them. JPA/Hibernate does. And they don't need any dependency to be injected anyway.

Comment: It's not a "good" idea to make your code dependent on ANY third party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means Entitys can be injected everywhere but we have this Demeter's law thing where objects should only communicate with their close neibour. Sure, we can say, we simply do not use them in Services but in DAO-Services only but we have no big winner at this time.

I mean I like the imagination of concentrate all Object-Constructions at one place. If someone ask, where is it created, we could say: "Spring created it".

Another reason is that a table might have a not-null column. If the JPA entity is a 100% database-compatible entity-bean it requires at least one Constructor-Argument that is unsupported by automatic-prototype-creation. We could drop that constructor-argument and move any violation agains that not-null column from the compile-time to the run-time, but if we drop that constructor-argument we also drop the fail-fast principle.

There also is a reason in the Dependency-Inversion-Principle. My reason here differs (respectfully) from that reason from Makoto a little bit. One of the ideas behind the DIP is

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules.

Would you agree with the idea that a entity created this way is low-level *modul* and the service who requires it is a high-level *modul*? So we loose this part of DIP.

Answer (score 2):

The principal benefit that Spring gives you is dependency injection and inversion of control.  When you are dealing with your JPA entities, you *absolutely* want control over their lifecycle, not just to deal with cascading operations (saves and deletes), but also for the sake of clarity and sanity.

Worse, this development style absolutely marries you to Spring; you can use JPA/Hibernate *without* Spring, and should you find yourself in a position wanting to migrate away from it, if you had your JPA entities wired through your framework, you'd find that divorce very, very difficult.

You don't want to let Spring manage these entities.  It adds significant complexity in the code base itself for little gain.

Comment: Spring respects the Named and Inject annotations, no need for a marriage with Spring.

Comment: @PeterRader:  I have my reservations that a team who would make the conscious decision to use Spring to inject their JPA entities would use `@Named` or `@Inject`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but would it make sense ?

No and for multiple reasons.
The most obvious one comes from the first reason to make an object a bean :

**Should we consider an entity as a dependency that we want to inject ?**
The answer is of course **no**.
So entities have not to be beans.

The lifecyle of entities is handled by the persistence context and not by the Spring container and you indeed never want to inject an entity but you want generally to create it in the methods : yourself or via the `EntityManager`.
So Spring is totally irrelevant here.